# Paypal Adaptive Payments - Finalizing payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, express-checkout

Is there anyway to have user finalize payment on my site instead of on paypal.com?  I want to run a script before sending off for final authorization (not just before redirecting and logging into paypal).

I know IPN would help but will not satisfy a race condition completely.

I know Express checkout can do this but I need someone to pay someone else, not direct payment to myself.  I don't think that's how Express checkout works if I read correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in your assumption on Express Checkout; although it can do split payments over multiple different receivers.

With regards to Adaptive Payments; you can still call the Pay API with actionType=CREATE and the transaction is only finalized once you've called the ExecutePayment API call.
See also page 123 in https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_AdaptivePayments.pdf

Comment: I thought Adaptive payments can split payments through its chained payments feature, not Express checkout. <br/>I think actionType=CREATE only works with implicit logins where the receiver is myself.<br/>I am trying to mimic ebay's checkout where you are brought to a summary page (on my site) that contains a Pay buttons that finalizes the payment.

Comment: That's a common misconception; Express Checkout can do split payments as well. It just can't do chained payments.

Comment: To answer your question; I believe it works for both, although I'm not entirely sure. You may want to double-check with PayPal Developer Support to be sure: https://www.paypal.com/dts/

Comment: Ok, you can use CREATE but you still have to finalize the payment through a paypal.com link where you log in and submit payment.  So I can't see any possible way of having the final click on my site.

Comment: 1. actionType CREATE 'works only for delayed payments. You can check this in sandbox mode. First person always gets paid once transaction is approved by the sender.

2. Regarding express checkout - I am checking now if it will solve your problem